# Golang regex for requiring multiple capture groups

Tags: regex

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm trying to match multiple capture groups, requiring one of each and can't see what's wrong. This is regex for Golang.

Given:

```
abc.com
abc.com/help
abc.com/win
abc.com/lose
abc.com/lose/wowyoulost
www.abc.com/win
www.abc.com/really/you/win
cde.com
cde.com/win
```

And the regex:

```
(abc\.com)+(win|lose)+
```

I am trying to require 1 or more of the first group and 1 or more of the second group. The intended outcome should be:

```
abc.com - NO MATCH
abc.com/help - NO MATCH
abc.com/win - MATCH
abc.com/lose - MATCH
abc.com/lose/wowyoulost - MATCH
www.abc.com/win - MATCH
www.abc.com/really/you/win - MATCH
cde.com - NO MATCH
cde.com/win - NO MATCH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `^abc\.com/(win|lose)`? See https://regex101.com/r/Gjpkl7/1. Note that your regex could not match the strings because there is no `/` in the pattern to match the `/` in the strings.

Comment: No, I'd want it to match www.abc.com as well, so no demarcation of start or ends - same for the text fragments on the back. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear, see `^(?:www\.)?abc\.com(?:/[^/]+)*/[^/]*(?:win|los[te])` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gjpkl7/2) (where all `[^/]` are replaced with `[^/\n]` since it is a single multiline string demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [lazy quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy): `.*?`:

`abc\.com/.*?(win|lose)`

See https://regex101.com/r/STl8t7/1